# zend framework stack trace

Tags: zend-framework

Is there a way to make stack trace to display the whole generated SQL statement when there is an error instead just the first few characters of it?

This is what it currently displays

> ...\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(220): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE "diction...', Array)

..and I would like to see the whole update statement before sent to the db to track what is wrong with it.

Thanks for the help.
SWK

Comment: I don't know the answer to this but it's one that bugs me as well.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to view the complete sql statement you can use Zend_Debug. For example if your sql statement is in the variable $select and you want to view the complete sql statement you can use the following line of code:

```
Zend_Debug::Dump($select);
exit;
```

Or if your code is created withe the Zend_Db_Table class you can use:

```
$select = new Zend_Db_Select(Zend_Registry::get('db'));
$select->from('string');
Zend_Debug::Dump($select->assemble());
exit;
```

I think the best way to view the sql statement is by using the profiling function on the database connection. This is combination withe the logging function and the firePHP add-on for Firefox is my favorite setup.

If you use the MVC configuration of Zend Framework this is done white this lines of code:

```
// setup the database connection
$db = Zend_Db::factory(Zend_Registry::get('config')->database->adapter,Zend_Registry::get('config')->database->params);

// create a new profiler
profiler = new Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug('All DB Queries');

// enable profiling (this is only recommended in development mode, disable this in production mode)
$profiler->setEnabled(true);
// add the profiler to the database object
$db->setProfiler($profiler);

// setup the default adapter to use for database communication
Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);

// register the database object to access it in other parts of the project
Zend_Registry::set('db',$db);

/**
*
* This part is optional
*
* You can use this logger to log debug information to the firephp add-on for Firefox
* This is handy for debugging but must be disabled in production mode
*
*/

// create logger
$logger = new Zend_Log();

// create firebug writer
$firebug_writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug();

// add writer to logger
$logger->addWriter($firebug_writer);

// register the logger object to access it in other parts of the project
Zend_Registry::set('log',$logger);
```

The firebug add-on (requirement for firephp) can be found on this website:
[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

The FirePHP add-on can be found on this website:
[FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/)

Ivo Trompert

Answer (score 3):

whilst the profiler is V cool - it doesn't help debug when the system throws an exception..

check out this post on giving a more detailed stack trace inc full SQL

ONLY TO BE USED IN DEV ENVIRONMENTS for obvious reasons

http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/blog/zend-framework/zend-framework-more-detailed-stack-trace/