# Getting a full stack trace from ZendFramework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, php

I have a very large web application which uses ZendFramework. There seems to be a syntax error in some SQL statement somewhere (a lot of stuff is automatically generated), but the logged error is very unhelpful (project information removed)

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near [...] in [...]/ZendFramework/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 [...]/ZendFramework/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 [...]/ZendFramework/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 [...]/ZendFramework/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 [...]/ZendFramework/Zend/Db/Adapter/ in [...]/ZendFramework/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 234
```

This stack trace contains only references inside the Zend Framework, and the actual caller (where the syntax error most likely is) is nowhere to be seen.

How do I get Zend Framework to give me a full stack trace whenever an error happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These exception should be being logged by your `ErrorController()`(*or whatever you have that passes as an ErrorController*) typically in the default module (*application/controllers/ErrorController.php*). If this is the case it should be pretty simple to alter the logging mechanism.

It may just take a little experimentation to figure out which [Exception()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) methods you need to use to get the output you need.

**[EDIT]**

I should have noted that the view would be simple place to update if you are using the default error setup:

```
<!-- application/views/scripts/error/error.phtml -->
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>An error occurred</h1>
        <h2><?php echo $this->message ?></h2>
        <?php if (isset($this->exception)): ?>
            <h3>Exception information:</h3>
            <p>
                <b>Message:</b> <?php echo $this->exception->getMessage() ?>
            </p>
            <h3>Stack trace:</h3>
            <pre><?php echo $this->exception->getTraceAsString() ?>
            <!-- add full Trace info -->
            <pre><?php echo $this->exception->getTrace() ?></pre>
            </pre>
            <h3>Request Parameters:</h3>
            <pre><?php echo $this->escape(var_export($this->request->getParams(), true)) ?>
            </pre>
        <?php endif ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a more detailed stack trace you can use:

```
foreach($this->exception->getTrace() as $t){
        var_dump($t);
    }
```

mentioned [here](http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/zend-framework/zend-framework-more-detailed-stack-trace/). But I think you're going better to use firebug and firephp and debug sql queries with Zend_Debug_Profiler_Firebug class, as described in this useful articles [here](http://www.peacocksuit.com/blog/tag/zend_db_profiler_firebug/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/332110/810568) and [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.profiler.html#zend.db.profiler.profilers.firebug).

Comment: Getting the full stack trace like that would be nice, if I knew where the exception is being thrown, so I can wrap it into a try-catch block. However, the error starts with "uncaught exception", so I don't know where the exception is thrown in the first place, and that's why I'm asking this question. Thanks for the links, I'll consider them for the next application, but adding a third party tool at this point is pretty much out of the question.